# Why do these sort in different order?

Tags: bash, sorting

I expect `01` to appear first or last in both of these sorts but actually changing the length of the second record changes the sort order. Why?

```
$ { echo 01; echo 0_12; } | sort
01
0_12

$ { echo 01; echo 0_1; } | sort
0_1
01
```

---

Even worse is this. Am I losing my mind?

```
$ { echo 01_; echo 0_1; } | sort
0_1
01_
$ { echo 01__; echo 0_12; } | sort
01__
0_12
```

Comment: **What locale do you have set?** On Unix (or Unixoid) many locales ignore underscore when sorting except to break ties, so you are actually sorting '01' before '012'

Comment: Wow. I did _not_ know that some locals ignore some characters except when breaking ties. That is news to me! I figured regardless of the environment the sort order of two characters would not change. But, apparently, that's not true! That seems like a bug farm waiting to happen. Why would they have allowed that? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: "Why would they have allowed that?" – Because it's useful. I'm Polish and I expect `Ł` to be between `L` and `M` in the alphabet. I guess you don't. A universal `sort` would never be able to make both of us happy. What about Greek or Russian? If you want `sort -f` (case-insensitive sort), you expect `i` and `I` to be the same letter. [In Turkish they are not the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I_in_computing). Different locale settings allow different behaviors. In my Debian `man 1 sort` includes an explicit `*** WARNING ***` about this.

Comment: What is unexpected is that the sort order of characters _within_ a given locale is not fixed. For example, if 0_1 sorts before 01_ then I'd expect appending any sequence X to the former and Y to the latter would result in the 0_1X to sort before 01_Y, but that's not the case. Why did they allow _that_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that

> The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set
> LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte
> values.

One solution might be, to explicitly set the locale:

```bash
{ echo 01; echo 0_12; } | env -i LC_COLLATE=C sort }
```